# Meteor template doesn't re-render even though its helper is called?

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, render

Ive got this template on the front end:

```
if tournament
            .tournament
                if round
                    each round
                        ul(class='round#{currentRound} of#{rounds}')
                            each match
                                li
                                    each participant
                                        if winner
                                            .participant.winner
                                                a(href='#')
                                                    span.participant-title #{displayName}
                                                    span.participant-number #{rank}
                                                    span.participant-id #{id}
                                                    span.participant-status #{status}
                                                    span.participant-round #{thisRound}
                                                    span.participant-match #{thisMatch}
                                        else if pending
                                            .participant
                                                a(href='#')
                                                    span.participant-title Waiting...
                                                    span.participant-number xxx
                                                    span.participant-id #{id}
                                                    span.participant-status #{status}
                                                    span.participant-pending
                                                    span.participant-disagree #{disagree}
                                                    span.participant-round #{thisRound}
                                                    span.participant-match #{thisMatch}
                                        else
                                            .participant.loser
                                                a(href='#')
                                                    span.participant-title #{displayName}
                                                    span.participant-number #{rank}
                                                    span.participant-id #{id}
                                                    span.participant-status #{status}
                                                    span.participant-round #{thisRound}
                                                    span.participant-match #{thisMatch}
                else
                    h1#not-found Tournament Not Found
```

and this helper:

```
tournament: function(){
    if (this.tournament) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
},
round: function() {
    var tournament = this.tournament.brackets;
    var rounds = tournament.length;
    var results = [];
    tournament.map(function(value, index){
        var currentRound = index + 1;
        results.push({rounds: rounds, currentRound: currentRound, matches: value});
    });
    return results;
},
match: function(){
    return this.matches;
},
participant: function(){
    var results = [];
    this.map(function (value, index) {
        var type = value['win'];
        var obj = {
            id: value['id'],
            rank: value['id'].slice(0,3),
            displayName: value['displayName'],
            thisRound: value['round'],
            thisMatch: value['match'],
            status: type,
            disagree: value['disagree']
        };
        if (value['disagree']) {
            console.log("value:", value);
        }
        if (type === true || type === 'undetermined') {
            obj.winner = true;
        }else if (type === 'pending'){
            obj.pending = true;
        }else{
            obj.loser = true;
        }

        results.push(obj);
    });
    return results;
}
```

The helper is getting ran everytime the tournament object changes... but the template only gets updated the first time my meteor method is called?

have you ever encoutered this before?
I can post my meteor method if that would help too.

Where I change data:

```
    Meteor.call('submitWinner', winnerInfo, thisCampaign._id, Meteor.user().apiKey, function(error, result) {
        // display the error to the user and abort
        if (error){
            return alert(error.reason);
        }else{
            // update css?
            var updateWaiting = $('.last-submitted').closest('.participant');
            // updateWaiting.html('<a href=#><span class=participant-title>Waiting...</span> <span class=participant-number>xxx</span></a>');
            // updateWaiting.removeClass('undetermined')
            $('#theaterMode').hide();
            $('.swearBox').hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: meteor templates are reactive, which means the helpers will be recalled only if do a Session.get('prop') inside the helper or you are querying a mongo dataset. from your code it looks like none of this done, probably the reason why its not working

Comment: I added where I do that.
It works on the first submit but not the second?